# Manually selecting a database for a QuerySet overrides database router methods in Django?

Tags: django, database

I'm using django 1.8, I want to define two databases, but I want to use one of them very rarely.

So I defined two databases and a default router like this:

```
DATABASES = { 
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': '...',
        ...
    },  
    'secondary': {
        'ENGINE': '...',
        ...
    }   
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['DefaultRouter']
```

and then defined DefaultRouter like this so `migrate` wouldn't have any effects on it:

```
DEFAULT = 'default'
class DefaultRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """Reads go to 'default'
        """
        return DEFAULT

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """Writes always go to 'default'
        """
        return DEFAULT

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """ Relations between objects are allowed if both objects are in the 'default' pool.
        """
        if obj1._state.db == DEFAULT and obj2._state.db == DEFAULT:
            return True
        return False

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if db == DEFAULT:
            return True
        else:   
            return False
```

Assume that I have a `Model` called `Book` which exists on both databases with different instances. I want to do a query on Book from my `secondary` database like this:
`books = Book.objects.using('secondary').filter(author="john")`

I have two questions now:

1- Does this query hits `secondary` database having that method in the Router to route all read/writes to the `default`? and more generally: `using()` overrides router's methods?

2- having `book = books.first()`, is it safe to call `book.author`? by safe I mean that it hits `secondary` database. or I have to use `using('secondary')` to have access to that object fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **[Refer to Django Docs Multi DBs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database)**

> Django also provides an API that allows you to maintain complete control over database usage in your code. A manually specified database allocation will take priority over a database allocated by a router.

2. Django filter is lazily evaluated so till you run book.author, book will contain a reference to `Book.objects.using('secondary').filter(author="john").first()` so it will be from the the secondary database.

However you might want to check this as well:
**[Save on Multi DBs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save)**

> If you’ve saved an instance to one database, it might be tempting to use save(using=...) as a way to migrate the instance to a new database. However, if you don’t take appropriate steps, this could have some unexpected consequences.